# Swapping the strings of two arrays in C

Tags: c

I am getting confused between pointers and variable names. I was trying to swap the strings between two arrays. However, I got an "error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token" while running it in an onlie compiler with the  void shift_change(*shift_array1, *shift_array2); functon

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Online C compiler to run C program online
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//Self Created Questions

void shift_change(*shift_array1, *shift_array2);
int main (int argc, char*argv[]){
    char shift_array1[][10]= {"Sun", "Tue", "Thu", "Sat"};
    char shift_array2[][10]= {"Mon", "Wed", "Fri"};


//char str_arr[2][6] = { {'g','o','u','r','i','\0'}, {'r',' a',' m','\0'}};
    shift_change(shift_array1,shift_array2);


}



//a void function to change and print out the shift

void shift_change(*shift_array1, *shift_array2){
    //get the number of values inside the arrays using size of function (only for arrays)
    int shift_nums1= sizeof(shift_array1)/sizeof(shift_array1[0]);
    int shift_nums2= sizeof(shift_array2)/sizeof(shift_array2[0]);


    char* new_array_1[shift_nums2][10];
    char* new_array_2[shift_nums1][10];

    //may need to get the strings one by one
   

   //for the first person;
    for (int i=0; i<shift_nums1; i++){
        //declaring temp to be swapped with shift_2 later;
        char* temp[shift_nums][10];

        strcpy(temp[i],shift_array1[i]);

    }  


    //for the second person;
    for (int j=0; j<shift_nums1; j++){
        //declaring temp to be swapped later;
        char* temp2[shift_nums][10];

        strcpy(temp2[j],shift_array2[j]);

    }  


    //Use strcpy to copy the strings from temp2 to array1 and temp1 to array2;

   

    //Create a new shift1 and shift2 ..., as the length of the original two arrays were different...

    for (int k=0; k<shift_nums2; k++){
        //declaring temp to be swapped with shift_2 later;
        char* temp[shift_nums][10];

        strcpy(new_array_1[k],shift_array1[k]);

    } 


    for (int x=0; x<shift_nums1; x++){
        //declaring temp to be swapped with shift_2 later;
        char* temp[shift_nums][10];

        strcpy(new_array_1[x],shift_array1[x]);

    }
    


}
```

I have not seen this error before and just wanted to ask what issue does this error mean. I tried to emulate a similar code, which was based on just swaping integers instead of arrays of strings, that also invovled using pointer variable

Comment: `void shift_change(*shift_array1, *shift_array2)` You have not provided the _type_ of the two arguments... Also: `sizeof(shift_array1)/sizeof(shift_array1[0]` The function _receives_ the two arguments as pointers. Within the called function, there is no array to take the size of. This is a pointer...

Answer (score 2):

You have forgot to specify the type of argument in the function declaration and definition:

```
void shift_change(*shift_array1, *shift_array2);
                  ^^^            ^^^
```

Even if you put `char` before them, it's not going to work because the arguments you are passing to them are `2D` array:

```
shift_change(shift_array1,shift_array2);
```

Type of `shift_array1` is `char [4][10]` and type of `shift_array2` is `char [3][10]`.

The type of arguments of `shift_change()` function should be `char [][10]` which is equivalent to `char (*)[10]`.

The function `shift_change()` if full of mistakes and UB's. I will point out the major ones.

Passing an array to a function and then using `sizeof` to get its size is wrong because when an array is passed to a function, it is converted to pointer to it's first element. So, the value you get from `sizeof` is the size of pointer and not array. In your case you should pass the size of array as well to the calling function or define them as constant or macro.

Other major problem is passing an uninitialized pointer to `strcpy()`. Whenever attempting to write to a pointer, make sure that it should point to a valid memory. Moreover, the type of pointer that you are passing is incompatible to the type of parameter of `strcpy()` library function.

Also, if you want to swap the elements of two array, make sure that both the array's are large enough to hold the elements of each other. In your program, `shift_array2` is not large enough to hold the elements of `shift_array1`.

To swap the elements of `shift_array1` and `shift_array2`, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum {ROW = 4, COL = 10};
void shift_change(char shift_array1[ROW][COL], char shift_array2[ROW][COL]);

int main (void) {
    char shift_array1[ROW][COL]= {"Sun", "Tue", "Thu", "Sat"};
    char shift_array2[ROW][COL]= {"Mon", "Wed", "Fri"};

    printf ("Before..\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i) {
        printf ("shift_array1[%d] : %-10s, shift_array2[%d] : %-10s\n",
                i, shift_array1[i], i, shift_array2[i]);
    }

    shift_change(shift_array1, shift_array2);

    printf ("After..\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i) {
        printf ("shift_array1[%d] : %-10s, shift_array2[%d] : %-10s\n",
                i, shift_array1[i], i, shift_array2[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void shift_change(char shift_array1[ROW][COL], char shift_array2[ROW][COL]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i) {
        char temp[COL];
        strcpy (temp, shift_array1[i]);
        strcpy (shift_array1[i], shift_array2[i]);
        strcpy (shift_array2[i], temp);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Before..
shift_array1[0] : Sun       , shift_array2[0] : Mon       
shift_array1[1] : Tue       , shift_array2[1] : Wed       
shift_array1[2] : Thu       , shift_array2[2] : Fri       
shift_array1[3] : Sat       , shift_array2[3] :           
After..
shift_array1[0] : Mon       , shift_array2[0] : Sun       
shift_array1[1] : Wed       , shift_array2[1] : Tue       
shift_array1[2] : Fri       , shift_array2[2] : Thu       
shift_array1[3] :           , shift_array2[3] : Sat
```